# Serving a file with Netty - response is truncated by one byte

Tags: java, android, nio, netty, android-assets

I've serving a files from Android assets via Netty server (images, html).
Text files such a html is saved as .mp3 to disable compression (I need an InputStream!)

My pipeline is looking like this:

```
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());

    pipeline.addLast("handler", new AssetsServerHandler(context));
```

My handler is:

```
public class AssetsServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

        // some checks

        final FileInputStream is;
        final AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = assetManager.openFd(path);
            is = afd.createInputStream();   
        } catch(IOException exc) {
            sendError(ctx, NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        final long fileLength = afd.getLength();

        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
        setContentLength(response, fileLength);

        final Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        final ChannelFuture future;
        ch.write(response);
        future = ch.write(new ChunkedStream(is));
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                future.getChannel().close();
            }
        });
        if (!isKeepAlive(request)) {
            future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

With that handler i've got my resposes truncated by at least one byte. If I change `ChunkedStream` to `ChunkedNioFile` (and so use a `is.getChannel()` instead of `is` as a constructor to it) - everything works perfectly.

Please, help me understand what is wrong with ChunkedStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right to me. Does the returned FileInputStream of AssetFileDescriptor contain "all the bytes" ? You could check this with a unit test. If there is no bug in it then its a bug in netty. I make heavy use of ChunkInputStream and never had such a problem yet, but maybe it really depends on the nature of the InputStream.

Would be nice if you could write a test case and open a issue at netty's github.

Comment: The `FileInputStream` i use is generated somewhere in Android's core. How can i unit-test it then? I think it is more up to Android than Netty. By the way, `Channel` i've got from this (the same!!) `FileInputStream` is working fine.

Comment: I would write a unit test that writes a sequence of bytes to a file. Then open the file with the AssetFileDescriptor, get the FileInputStream and read all bytes out of it. Then check for every byte if its equal the byte that you have written to the file before. You should test this for different FileInputStream.read(...) method...

Comment: Let me know what are your findings